# Background Service in Cordova (with Crosswalk)

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have a javascript app and I package it with Crosswalk. I have another javascript module that handles MQTT nofitications from my own MQTT server. I need that my app remains handling MQTT notifications even when app is not visible, like an Android service.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, more or less. I solve it by using a Cordova Plugin, and calling Java native code (for Android) and starting an Android Service that handle MQTT. Unfortunately, it is not possible to use MQTT client in background from Javascript.

Comment: This is a basic tutorial to create cordova plugins https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html